# Simple bouncing ball in Visual Basic not working without reason

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, bounce

The code for a bouncing ball (which has worked in the past, recreating from memory) I wrote will not work. When the ball should reflect off the side and continue in that direction it simply reverts and hits the wall again. After hitting the side, the ball just flickers between two positions.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim XVel As Integer = 10
Dim YVel As Integer = 20
Dim XPos As Integer = 12
Dim YPos As Integer = 12

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    pbBall.Left = XPos
    pbBall.Top = YPos


    Label1.Text = XPos
    Label2.Text = YPos
    Label3.Text = YVel
    Label4.Text = XVel

    XPos += XVel
    YPos += YVel



    If pbBall.Top <= 0 Then
        YVel = YVel * -1
    End If

    If pbBall.Left <= 0 Then
        XVel = XVel * -1
    End If

    If pbBall.Bottom >= Me.Height Then
        YVel = YVel * -1
    End If

    If pbBall.Right >= Me.Width Then
        XVel = XVel * -1
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I cannot tell what is going wrong and have been fooling around with it for an hour or two now.

Comment: You need to do more debugging.  Make it fail faster by starting pbBall at (0, 0) and initializing XVel and YVel to negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the code does :
Say, your frame has a height of 100 pixels and your ball a size (diameter) of 10 pixels.
Then, your ball is moving down at a velocity of 20 (positive) and is at the time at 80 pixels from the top (way above bottom frame)

What happens when Timer1_Tick is called :

```
    pbBall.Top = YPos ' which were calculated from the previous call
    ' pbBall.Top becomes 100 (which were 80 + 20)
    ' ...
    YPos += YVel ' prepares the next location, YPos becomes 100 + 20 = 120
    ' ...
    ' Then comes your conditional tests :
    If pbBall.Bottom >= Me.Height Then
        YVel = YVel * -1 ' YVel => 20 * -1 = -20
    End If
    ' pbBall.Bottom is .Top + .Size = 100 + 10 = 110
    ' so the condition is True, so YVel becomes -20
    ' Sound good isn't it ?
    ' BUT IT ISN'T !
```

Before Timer1_Tick is called a secund time, your pbBall.Top is 100, and your YVel is -20. Should go up, but it wont...

```
    pbBall.Top = YPos ' .. and YPos were 120,
    ' because Velocity +20 were added before it was switched to -20
    ' your ball is now way below the frame.
    ' ...
    YPos += YVel ' where YVel were switched to -20 as expected.
    ' But 120 - 20 = 100
    ' Note that top position "100" will be used the NEXT time Timer1_Tick is called,
    ' NOT at the moment the condition test performed below occurs..!

    ' ANYWAY, your If condition is True one more time :
    If pbBall.Bottom >= Me.Heigt Then ' Bottom = 120 + 10 = 130
        YVel = YVel * -1 ' YVel = -20 * - 1 = 20 => Your ball will go down again !
    End If

    ' When Timer1_Tick is called again, the Ball will rise at 110, 
    ' but next location will move it down again at 130...
    ' and again, and again...
```

One simple thing fixes the basic algorythm : Move this piece of code :

```
    XPos += XVel
    YPos += YVel
```

**at the very end** of your Timer1_Tick method (before the End Sub) This will update the NEXT location of your ball **AFTER** velocity has been switched and prevent your ball from overflowing boundaries TWICE. Actually, when your ball collides with a boundary, your code doesn't make it bounce immediately, but let it go further one more time. So, it is trapped in an endless velocity switch...

Side note :
That's my nine-th post on StackOverflow. Sorry if it doesn't fit well yet. Sorry if it's long.. I'm french speaking and I'm unsure what I write is correct. I'm no expert and I may be wrong; feel free to correct me :) I just like VB, saw the question, thought I could help, and voila !

Side Note 2 :
I don't know if it's appropriate to make suggestions, but :

- If you're dealing only with one ball, why not use a Frame structure sightly smaller than the control (margin the size of your ball) and assume your ball is a dot (point) This allow you to discard Right, Bottom and Size Properties. Of course, from the moment you want more balls that can collide eachover, this approach becomes useless.
- About the fact that the ball can overflow boundaries (even with the fix) you could think of a more precise calculation of the next location of the ball, (XPos = XVel - XPos when the ball collides with the left boundary. On the right, it's a bit more complicated)
- You could also use `IsMovingLeft As Boolean` (`IsMovingUp`) to avoid multiplying X/YVel by -1 each time. Just a suggestion though :)
- And finally, I would have put XVel and YVel as properties of the Ball, not global variables, in that way, I could have multiple balls with different velocities.

Answer (score 1):

### Reason:

If the `Top` becomes 0, and `XPos`=-1, so you change the direction. 
Next round, Top becomes -1, XPos = 0, and you change the direct again. You will keep repeating this for ever.

### Solution:

When you change all directions, you should recalculate XPos and YPos.  For example:

```
If pbBall.Right >= Me.Width Then
    XVel = XVel * -1
End If
XPos = pbBall.Left
YPos = pbBall.Top
XPos += XVel
YPos += YVel
```